# React Native FlatList BUG?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to render a footer in FlatList,but got some strange:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // bind this for these 4 functions, cause FlatList footer can not be render
    this._renderFooter=this._renderFooter.bind(this)
    this._onEndReached=this._onEndReached.bind(this)
    this._separator = this._separator.bind(this)
}
```

FlatList:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.dataArray}
    renderItem={this._renderItemView}

    ListFooterComponent={this._renderFooter}
    onEndReached={this._onEndReached}
    onEndReachedThreshold={1}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this._separator}
    // BUG here: above functions which has been bind this in component constructor, FlatList Footer would not render

    // // below functions called bind this here, FlatList Footer renders fun
    // ListFooterComponent={this._renderFooter.bind(this)}
    // onEndReached={this._onEndReached.bind(this)}
    // onEndReachedThreshold={1}
    // ItemSeparatorComponent={this._separator.bind(this)}
/>
```

If i put all these functions bind call in constructor, FlatList can not render its footer with _renderFooter function as expected.

demo project: https://github.com/xilibro/ReactNativeFlatListDemo

Comment: `ListFooterComponent` has to be a `ReactClass` not a function.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/flatlist.html#listfootercomponent

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
            ListFooterComponent={<Footer {...this.props}/>}
```

Where Footer is

```
    const RTFooter = (props) =>{
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

    RTFooter.propTypes = {

    };

export default RTFooter;
```

Footer should be class

Another Option will be to use arrow functions (Better)

```
 renderFooter = () =>{
    return(<View/>);
    }
```

and then

```
 ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
```